# Could not get every words inside span element in Selenium automate tool?

Tags: python, selenium

Using Selenium automate tool, I tried to automate on this simple [online typing site](https://onlinetyping.org/typing-test/typing-test-wpm-10minutes.php).

So, my automate script goes like this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

browser     = webdriver.Chrome('/home/narun/Downloads/soft/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver_linux64 (1)/chromedriver')
URL = 'https://onlinetyping.org/typing-test/typing-test-wpm-10minutes.php'
browser.get(URL)

time.sleep(3) # waiting every elements finish loading

wordsection = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#word-section span')

wordlist = []
text = ''

for span in wordsection:
    if span.text !='':
        wordlist.append(span.text)

if wordlist:
    text = ' '.join(wordlist)

print text # text for typing

typebox = browser.find_element_by_id('typebox')
typebox.send_keys(text)
```

After opening a website, I paused my script for 3 seconds in case some elements are not ready loading.

Then after I got those words inside span elements of ID word-section section, I generated them into a text ready for typing input.

However, my problem is I could get only half of typing, thought. From inspecting element, I found every typing words is already inside `span` element of ID `#word-section`, but why my selector script could not get all of them? Thanks.

Comment: a lot of them are not visible so webdriver won't find them.  You could use javascript to get them...

Comment: Also this typing site is fun, even if you finish the typing before 10 minutes, it will not give you the results. No matter if you are good or a bot, you will need to wait :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I totally agree with @pcalkins comment, you have a lot of words, using find_elementS will run pretty slow, run a javascript and do whatever you want with the result, also, stop the usage of the sleep and use WebDriverWait as the code bellow:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/narun/Downloads/soft/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver_linux64 (1)/chromedriver')
URL = 'https://onlinetyping.org/typing-test/typing-test-wpm-10minutes.php'
browser.get(URL)

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.waiting')))

script = 'return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(\'#word-section span\')).map(cell => cell.innerText)'
word_list = browser.execute_script(script) # ['word1', 'word2', ...]
text = ' '.join(word_list)

type_box = browser.find_element_by_id('typebox')
type_box.send_keys(text)
```

Comment: @SpencerMelo, sorry for reply. it's quite a great fun as a part of my learning about Selenium tool. Thanks very much for your help :)